# What movie has sunlight killing people and an office worker trying reach his pregnant wife?

Tags: story-identification

I'm not sure how old this movie is, but I watched it about a year ago on Hulu.

In the movie, an office worker leaves his pregnant wife at home and goes to work in an office building. He finds out, however, that sunlight hurts you really bad and so he cannot return home.  After a few days trapped in the building, he breaks through from the parking garage to a nearby subway tunnel.

The guy is fixated on either getting home or to his wife's parents' house. He makes it to one of those places and in the last 10 minutes of the movie he is right across from the house in another building.  His wife comes out and he walks across the road and gets really hurt by the sun, but he is nonetheless alive to see his wife.

What movie is this?

Comment: Probably the same movie but with accepted answer: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/260135/movie-where-everyone-becomes-agoraphobic/260136

Answer (score 24):

The movie is *[The Last Days](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1935914/)*.

> A mysterious epidemic spreads across the planet. Humanity develops an irrational fear of open spaces that causes instant death. Soon, the world population is trapped inside buildings. As Barcelona descends into chaos, Marc sets off on a quest to find Julia, his missing girlfriend, without ever going outside.
>
> <sub><sup>[Wikipedia: The Last Days](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1935914/)</sup></sub>

The people in the movie are ***not actually hurt by sunlight, but rather have a fear of being outside that is so strong it can literally kill them***. I watched this movie on Netflix a few months back and really enjoyed it.

Comment: Nice work.  Welcome to SFF:SE.

Comment: Good find. I didn't think of this when he described it.

Answer (score 0):

A partial match is *[Into the Night](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Into_the_Night_(TV_series))*, a TV series which involves a plane of survivors in a world where sunlight kills. However, it came out in 2020, does not involve an office building, and does not have a plot point of a pregnant wife.

> The first season follows a group of people whose plane is hijacked while they are on board a red-eye flight from Brussels. Terenzio (Cassetti), the hijacker, is an Italian NATO soldier. He forces his way onto the commercial aircraft and demands an early take-off. The handful of people in the aircraft now become some of the survivors from a deadly global event caused by exposure to sunlight. The plane heads west in an attempt to survive this catastrophe that kills all living organisms during daylight hours. The group – led by Mathieu (Capelluto), the pilot, and Sylvie (Pauline Étienne), a passenger – must work together to keep the sun behind them. The group must deal with fuel shortage, irradiated food, hidden agendas, and other problems in their race to reach an underground military bunker.
>
> In the second season, the remaining survivors secure their path to a NATO bunker, where they seek refuge from the deadly rays of the sun. Continuing their quest of survival with the military members in the bunker, they attempt to manage a burgeoning conflict and find a solution to the diminished supply of resources.

### Trailer

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! If it's not an answer, then please don't post it as one.

Comment: I'm a fan of post-apocalyptic content, I am not an malware agent or an troll. My apologies for misunderstanding. I eagerly wanted to provide a recommendation above rather than an answer.  Thanks for your patience and understanding. I also needed to log out and just mailed to help desk.  All the best.

Comment: I've expanded this so that it's at least a decent partial answer